# unable to convert password to "1.0 "to 1

Tags: java

Input Value for Password is retriving from Ecxel as "1.0" instead as 1 so trying to convert to integer.

```
int pswd =0;
pswd= Integer.parseInt(Dataset_TS_Login_Navigation.get"Password"));
```

now i am getting error as :

> exception_name = java.lang.NumberFormatException
>   exception_message = For input string: "9.0"

Answer (score 5):

`Dataset_TS_Login_Navigation.get"Password")` is returning 9.0 (A double)

Convert it from a `String` to a `Double` and then cast to an `Integer`.

```
int paswd = (int) Double.parseDouble(Dataset_TS_Login_Navigation.get"Password"));
```

Alternatively, if you can, just use it as a `double`:

```
double paswd = Double.parseDouble(Dataset_TS_Login_Navigation.get"Password"));
```